# How to use Ajax within nested composite components?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I've problems to ajaxify a nested composite component. I'm using them in the following way. (I've tried to reduce the example as much as possible!)

Basic composite component **base.xhtml**

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:clientBehavior name="update" event="click" targets="#{cc.clientId}:form:submit" default="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:form id="form">
        // ... some basic content
        <h:commandButton type="submit" id="submit" value="update"/>
    </h:form>   
</composite:implementation>
```

The composite component **reuse.xhtml** which reuses first composite component

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:clientBehavior name="update" event="update" targets="#{cc.clientId}:test" default="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <my:base id="test">
        <composite:insertChildren />
    </my:base>
</composite:implementation>
```

Use of these components

```
// Ajax works and method "void update(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)" is exeuted
<my:base>
    <f:ajax event="update" listener="#{controller.update}" render=":some-components"/>
</my:base>

// Ajax doesn't work, so nothing is executed, page reloads according to form submit
<my:reuse>
    <f:ajax event="update" listener="#{controller.update}" render=":some-components" />
</my:reuse>
```

My problem is mainly situated within `reuse.xhtml` because I don't know which target should be used within the `<composite:clientBehavior targets="???">` to ajaxify the commandButton within the base component and which event should be used. I've also tried to target the commandButton within the base component through `<composite:clientBehavior name="update" event="click" targets="#{cc.clientId}:test:form:submit" default="true"/>` within the declaration of `reuse.xhtml`, but without any success.

Comment: Don't add #{cc.clientId}, instead try targets="form:submit".

Comment: The `<cc:clientBehavior>` retarget in `reuse.xhtml` should do it. To be sure, I even created a testcase here based on the information provided so far and it works outright for me on Mojarra 2.1.13 and Tomcat 7.0.30. The `#{cc.clientId}:` part is indeed superfluous, but it shouldn't harm. At least, it works for me as good with or without it.

Comment: @BalusC could you please post the `<cc:clientBehavior>` which you've used within your testcase?

Comment: It's exactly the one as in your question (I only used `cc:` instead of `composite:` as that's how I've declared the CC namespace, but that shouldn't matter).

Comment: I only was a little bit confused because there originally were two possible definitions of `<cc:clientBehavior>` within the post, but finally everthings works fine! I've removed the `cc.clientId` from the targets definitions and that does the trick for me, on Mojarra 2.1.5 and JBoss AS 6.1. I will test again if this really was the trick or if it was a cleanup problem of the AS..

Comment: I meant the one as mentioned in *"I've also tried to target the commandButton within the base component through [...]"*

Comment: Damn I hate it if I could not reconstruct an error. Removing the `cc.clientId` did not do the trick. Don't really know where the mistake was! Thanks anyway!